# How to set the orders of jars in Weblogic EAR?

Tags: weblogic, classloader

I have an EAR file that contains two different jars that share some classes with an identical package+class name. This results in importance of classloading *inside* the EAR file itself.

How can I tell Weblogic to load one jar from APP-INF/lib before loading a different one in the same APP-INF/lib? I need to define a specific order to that if there is a conflict, it will take from JAR a and not JAR b.

I'm using Webogic 11g (10.3).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The top-level element in `weblogic-application.xml` has an optional classloader-structure element that you probably want to look into. For instance you can do something like:

```
   <classloader-structure> 
     <module-ref> 
       <module-uri>ejb1.jar</module-uri> 
     </module-ref>
     <module-ref> 
       <module-uri>web3.war</module-uri> 
     </module-ref>

     <classloader-structure> 
        <module-ref> 
           <module-uri>web1.war</module-uri> 
        </module-ref> 
     </classloader-structure>

   </classloader-structure>
```

Read more about declaring custom class loading at these [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/classloading.htm#WLPRG293). You may also find the Classloader Analysis Tool (CAT) at the same link of interest.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The thing is - I was already aware of this option, but the problem is that my jars are not modules. Not EJB jars or WARs. Just standard supporting LIB jars. Those cannot be defined in the xml.

Comment: @user3447647 Hi i am facing simillar issue, did you get any solution to this problem?

Comment: facing exact same issue, packaged my libs into shared-lib.jar putting lal jars into app-inf/lib folder but no dice, keep getting classnotfoundexception for classses that should be visible and sharedlibs are picked up by weblogic and by components that use them

Comment: @Kin - it sounds like maybe you need <prefer-application-packages> or you could simply add the jars into you $DOMAIN/lib folder and see what happens. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/classloading.htm#WLPRG314 . If that doesn't help, feel free to add a new question with your specific details

Comment: nope, that's not what i need, the problem is at the classloader level, this feature is not very well thought out, hence lack of indepth documentation, it doesn't consider all nuances of classloading, for example APP-INF/lib in application ear file is loaded differently than a shared library, just a hint for future seakers: if you keep getting classnotfound exceptions, you appl is not loading classes correctly (your app cannot see them) have a read here and think about it and you should figure it out http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/classloading.html#wp1097187

Comment: @Kin - if you found a good solution - consider adding another answer here so other users can find it easily. Cheers

Comment: Just added Class-Path entry in the manifest for the shared libs so that the classloader could find them... u cannot use classloader-stucture for shared libs, just fyi

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting ClassNotFound exceptions, try checking out the MANIFEST.MF for each of your modules to see if the "Class-Path" attribute is correctly populated with the locations of your jars in your APP-INF/lib - I've just spent a week or more tearing my hair out trying to find a solution to a similar problem, and this is what fixed it.