# How to specify order of JAR class loading in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have an EAR file that contains two different jars that share some classes with an identical package.class name. These JARs are deployed in my APP-INF/lib directory.

Let's say A jar contains the latest version of classes and B contains the old version of classes. When a class is referenced Weblogic looks first into B jar and loads the old version which break some functionality.

How can I tell Weblogic to load jar A before B from APP-INF/lib? I need to define a specific order to avoid loading old classes.

I have already tried adding A jar to `<classloader-structure>` in `weblogic-application.xml` like so:

EAR structure:

```
EAR
\--->A.jar
\--->webapp.war
.....
```

weblogic-application.xml:

```
<classloader-structure> 
    <module-ref> 
        <module-uri>A.jar</module-uri> 
    </module-ref> 
    .......
 </classloader-structure>
```

but then it throws error saying

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: classloader-structure element in weblogic-application.xml is referencing the module-uri A.jar which does not exist in this application.
```

Also one thing to remember is that A.jar is not a module, war or EJB it just a plain hibernate library: `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`

I am using Weblogic 12c version.

Comment: It might be possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721922/how-to-set-the-orders-of-jars-in-weblogic-ear

Comment: Will this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG282) help you ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set parent last strategy for class-loader, refer http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0551.html, as i remember there is a GUI in weblogic server to do the same.

Comment: Hi amit, actually i have other components in EAR other than web -app which i have not listed out. Basically the class name and package name is same but i want it to load classes from A.jar first say then B.jar

Comment: can you set weblogic classpath and put the required project library in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, currently i am just doing that. But i wanted to have a robust solution, something that i can change on configuration level.